# Best module where you create a block and select a node from drop-down to render?

Tags: views, 7, nodes, blocks

It's been a short while since I played with Drupal 6 and now I'm getting my feet wet in Drupal 7.7.

I need to be able to create a simple block and in that block 'configure' area I want to be able to simply choose a node in the system from a drop-down list. When that block renders on XXXX page, it will then render the teaser for that node along with any other variables set.

I thought I could do this with Views 3.x by just creating a block view which only renders one result and takes a node title as an argument. The new Views 3.x interface has me a little confused though. Not quite sure how to set it so the node title argument is configured in the block admin area and that argument is then always passed with the block view renders.

I guess what I sort of was looking for was an exposed filter in the block admin edit page where the value is saved but that doesn't seem possible. Anyone have any module suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Nodes In Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodesinblock) module seems to give you the desired outcome - albeit a different workflow to what you described. Here is an excerpt about it from the module's project page:

> ... makes it possible to add nodes into a block. A number of configurable blocks are generated which you can assign to a region. Visibility settings of this block are automatically set to 'Show on only the listed pages'. On the node content form, you define the weight and visibility per node thus making it easier for content administration as all your content is now in the same place. With this module, you don't have to explain your customers how blocks work but is still able to decide on which pages content must be rendered.